# How do I determine the continuity of this function? $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2y}{x+y} & x+y\neq 0\\1 & x+y=0.\end{cases}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I managed to solve a similar exercise, but on a circle and I leave below my idea on a circle.

Example: $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\sin(x^2+y^2) & x^2+y^2\leq 4\\1 & x^2+y^2>4\end{cases}$

The solution I made. I hope it is okay

The domains are: $\overline{D}(0,2)$ And the other domein is the exterior of $\overline{D}(0,2)$.

So we can problem on the intersection of the two domains, that is, on the circle: $C(0,2)$
$x^2+y^2=r^2,$ 
$r>0$
$f(x,y)=g(r)=\begin{cases} \sin(r^2), &r\leq 2\\ 1, &r>2\end{cases}$.
If we consider a point on the circle, for example (0.2) we can see that the limit is different.
so the function is not continuous.

How can I prove, on the same model, perhaps, that the constrained function on $x + y$ is continuous or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not continuous. You see that, along the line $x=0$, the function is $f(0,y) =0$ for $y\neq 0$. Thus, the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along this line is zero. One the other hand, the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the line $y=-x$ is 1. Since the limit along two different lines do not agree, there can be no limit.